# how to customize uialertview with textview?

Tags: iphone

here my problem is how to decrement the size uilaertview?

thanks

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100)];

```
alert.title = @"Terms of Service";
alert.message = @"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n";
alert.delegate = self;
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Review"];


[alert addSubview:textView];
[alert show];
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
alert.message = @"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

set your **alert.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 50, 50);** and use a simple message instead of using alert.message = @"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n";

Eg:

```
alert.message = @"my message";
```

or use the below UIAlertView delegate to set the frame

```
- (void)willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView{

    alertView.center =  your own CGPoint;
}
```